# Где лучше размещать методы кастомной выборки из БД в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

Начал изучать фреймворк Laravel. В примерах документации выборки данных расположены прямо в контроллерах по типу:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $users = DB::table('users')->get();
        ...
    }
}
```

Вопрос в следующем: как лучше отделить методы по выборки от контроллера? В обычных моделях, или в моделях Eloquent?

Comment: Eloquent - встроенные модели laravel, и логику работы с таблицами лучше в моделях держать. Прочитай раздел по работе с БД полностью. А фасад DB лучше использовать в крайних случаях, ведь все модели laravel также содержат методы билдера запросов, как и `DB`

Comment: Тогда получается по пути app\ будут расположены модели Eloquent для каждой таблицы + обычные модели. И как при этом не запутаться где какая модель?

Comment: И я не увидел в документации пример кастомной выборки в моделях Eloquent. То-есть все-равно сама выборка происходит за пределами моделей Eloquent. Тогда где ее можно разместить?

Comment: В официальной документации два раздела по БД - [Database](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database) и отдельно раздел по [Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent). Но кратко если, ты в моделях можешь создавать свои методы (публичные), в которых зашиваешь кастомные запросы к БД

Comment: А также посмотри главу про т.н. [query scopes (заготовки запросов)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#query-scopes)

Comment: А как лучше разделить модели от Eloquent ORM чтоб не запутаться? Они же находятся по одинаковому расположению.

Comment: Воспринимай Eloquent ORM как декоратор модели в рамках laravel и создавай модели командой `php artisan make:model ModelName`. А вот пример заготовки запроса в модели https://yadi.sk/d/ti1VQXxC3YifWL